# jQuery getJSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat, get

Im creating a dynamic web project, using Tomcat and im having some issues in sending/recieving data in jQuerys getJSON method.

What I have is:

```
    $('#selectNone').click(function(){

      var method = "getWellList";
       $.getJSON("HandleGet",{Method:method},
          function(data) {        
              $.each(data, function(i, field){
                     $("#dynamicCheck").append(field + " ");
```

It then appears in my doGet in java which I then create an XML, convert the XML to JSON.
XML looks like this:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <mobileApp>
       <wellList>
       <well uid="0" name="Well0"/>
       <well uid="1" name="Well1"/>
       <well uid="2" name="Well2"/>
       </wellList>
       </mobileApp>
```

Which creates a JSON like this:

```
           [[
{
"@uid": "0",
"@name": "Well0"
           },
{
"@uid": "1",
"@name": "Well1"
           },
{
"@uid": "2",
"@name": "Well2"
            }
           ]]
```

I cant find any good documentation on parsing the JSON response in jQuery and using to populate a checkbox control group.

Can anyone help me?
Is the JSON correct? Im using http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html to convert from XML to JSON.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can read xml nodes with jquery .. already try ?

Comment: Never tried with XML nodes. This is just a prototype at the moment. There will be a further back end module that returns JSON (converted from XML) that will populate the response. Just not really sure how it all fits together. Firebug doesnt pick up that I have JSON objects in the response. Very confused

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, the flickr example, and check the flickr return, and the iteration over return.

Comment: Ok, Ive changed the for each to:

 $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
           $("#dynamicCheck").append(item + " ");

Im confused where data.items comes from too? Sorry, im a little new at using jQuery and been working on this for the last 8 hours :(

Comment: I end up with Object is undefined in Firebug

Comment: Object is undefined:

(?)(data=[[Object { @uid="0", @name="Well0"}, Object { @uid="1", @name="Well1"}, Object { @uid="2", @name="Well2"}]])

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the jQuery documentation for $.each?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah ive had a look through the documentation. Must be where im going wrong. My div changes to had [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] within it. No idea what to change the for to...

Answer (score 0):

Sure .. try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.get ( "http://127.0.0.1/Code/doc.xml" , {} , function ( data ) {
                var cnt = { } ;
                $.each ( $(data).find ( 'well' ) , function ( i , node ) {
                    cnt [ i ] = { 
                        "@uid" : $(node).attr('uid'),
                        "@name" : $(node).attr('name')
                    }
                    $ ( '#data' ) . append ( $(node).attr ( 'name' ) + '<br />' ) ; 
                } ) ;
                console.log(cnt);
            } ) ;   
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
```

And doc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mobileApp>
   <wellList>
          <well uid="0" name="Well0" />
          <well uid="1" name="Well1" />
          <well uid="2" name="Well2" />
   </wellList>
</mobileApp>
```